# How to check if string contains a substring at the end?

Tags: c

I have a string (in this case a website ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com))), and I want to check that it ends with .com . How can I do it?

Here is what I tried:

```
compName(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int i = 0, c = 0;
    for (i; str2[i] != 0; i++)
        str2[i] = 0;
    while (str1[i] != '.')
        i++;
    i++;
    while (str1[i] != '.')
    {
        str2[c] = str1[i];
        i++;
        c++;
    }
    str2[i] = 0;
    if (str2[0] >= 97 && str2[0] <= 122)
        str2[0] = str2[0] - 32;
    printf("%s", str2);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you `strstr()`?

Comment: the input is by the user so i can't know where is the '.com' ending is

Comment: Fun fact: you can compare directly to a `char` literal rather than relying on the ASCII code. Makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your function has problems:

- you omit the return type, this is no longer supported by Standard C.
- The first `for` loop effectively erases the string pointed to by `str2`.  There is no guarantee it even has a null terminator.
- the `while` loop invokes undefined behavior if the `str1` does not contain a `.` or if it is shorter than `str2`.
- do not hardcode ASCII values such as `97` or `122`. It is neither portable not even readable.  Use `'a'` and `'z'` or preferably the functions defined in `<ctype.h>`.

Here is a simple string function for your purpose:

```
int str_ends_with(const char *s, const char *suffix) {
    size_t slen = strlen(s);
    size_t suffix_len = strlen(suffix);

    return suffix_len <= slen && !strcmp(s + slen - suffix_len, suffix);
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of '!strcmp(s + slen - suffix_len, suffix);' at the end?

Comment: @Opohass: `str_ends_with` return 1 if and only if the `suffix` string is at most as long as the string and comparing the end of the string with the suffix returns `0`, ie: if `suffix` is a suffix of `str`.

Comment: @Opohass: I left out the case issue, you can easily write a case independent version of `str_ends_with` in terms of a case independent `strcasecmp()` or `stricmp()`.

Comment: @Opohass the `!` in front of the `strcmp` call means `== 0`. Since `strcmp` returns 0 when the strings are equal, this is exactly what the function needs. Using `!` as an abbreviation for `== 0` is discouraged though in beginner's code, since it should only be used with boolean values.

Comment: @RolandIllig: `!strcmp(a, b)` is an idiom for testing equality of 2 strings. `strmp(a, b) == 0` is equivalent but not necessarily more readable.